# Chrome SVG Font incorrect rendering

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, canvas, fonts

Im noticing a bug in google chrome, Version 30.0.1599.101 m

When using an SVG font, the font renders correctly in the dom, but not correctly on the canvas element.

Here is an example
http://jsfiddle.net/Bodman/9M5ma/

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'robotobold';
    src: url(http://darkroast.net/canvas/roboto_bold_macroman/Roboto-Bold-webfont.svg#robotobold) format('svg');
}
```

I know this is a similar question, yet no real answer found.
[Chrome rendering SVG font on <canvas> with random characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617187/chrome-rendering-svg-font-on-canvas-with-random-characters)

Any solutions to this problem?